# HttpSession Url rewriting not working properly with servlet technology

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets, url-rewriting

i want to maintain session values for both servlet7 and servlet8 using http session url rewriting techniques, but the session is not working in tomcat server with the below codes.

request Flow1:-
httpsessionurlrewriting.jsp ---> servlet7.java

request Flow2:-
sendmorevalues1.jsp -----> servlet8.java ---- > AllItems.java

i want to maintain servlet7 and servlet8 values in session, and read that session values in Allitems.java using session url rewriting tehnique

this is my home page of App /SessionHandling/WebContent/HttpSessionUrlRewritingMain.jsp

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Http url rewriting technique</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Homepage1 sending request to servlet7 and setting attributes to session object</h1>
 <form action="Servlet7" method="get">
 Enter rollno<input type="text" name ="no"> <br>
 Enter name<input type="text" name="name"><br>
 <input type="submit" value="send rn and nm to servlet7"> 
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Servlet7.java

```
public class Servlet7 extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
String num = request.getParameter("no");
String name = request.getParameter("name");
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
response.setContentType("text/html");
PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
writer.print("<h1>Servlet 7 home page</h1>");
session.setAttribute("rollnum", num);
session.setAttribute("name", name);

int maxInactiveInterval = session.getMaxInactiveInterval();
writer.println("session expire time" + maxInactiveInterval + "  session id  " + session.getId()+"<br>");
session.setMaxInactiveInterval(-25);
writer.println("session expire time" + maxInactiveInterval + "  session id  " + session.getId()+"<br>");
response.encodeRedirectURL("Servlet8");
writer.println("<br><a href='Servlet8'>Click here to add more values to cart</a>");
writer.close();
```

Second request home page:-/SessionHandling/WebContent/SendMoreValues1.jsp

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Http url rewriting technique</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Homepage2 sending request to servlet8 and setting attributes to session object</h1>
 <form action="Servlet8" method="get">
 Enter email<input type="text" name ="eml"> <br>
 Enter pswd<input type="text" name="pw"><br>
 <input type="submit" value="send eml and pwd to servlet8"> 
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Servlet8.java

```
public class Servlet8 extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private PrintWriter writer;
protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
try {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    writer = response.getWriter();
    String email = request.getParameter("eml");
    String pswd = request.getParameter("pw");
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
    session.setAttribute("email", email);
    session.setAttribute("password", pswd);
    int maxInactiveInterval = session.getMaxInactiveInterval();
    writer.println("session timout time" + maxInactiveInterval + "  sesssion id" + session.getId());
    response.encodeURL("AllItems");
    writer.print(request.getSession().getId());
    writer.println("<a href='AllItems'>Click here to display all cart values from Allitems servlet</a>");
    writer.print("all values are set");
    writer.close();

} catch (Exception e) {
    writer.print("session object not found by container, session id not be received from request");
}
}
}
```

Allitems.java

```
public class AllItems extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private PrintWriter writer;
@Override
protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
try {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    writer = response.getWriter();
    Enumeration<String> names = session.getAttributeNames();
    while (names.hasMoreElements()) {
    String string = names.nextElement();
    writer.println("<h4>" + string + " :  " + session.getAttribute(string).toString() + "</h4>");
    }
    writer.print("all values are retrieved");
//    session.invalidate();
    writer.print("session object inavlidated/destroyed");
    writer.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    writer.print(" old session object not found... ");
    }

}
```

}

am using eclipse Ide, and apache tomcat server8,

Comment: What do you want to retrieve in AllItems servlet?

Comment: all the session values of servlet7  and servlet8

Comment: What's the output of your current code?

Comment: After submitting two indiviudal requests from individual html pages OUtput on browser is....:-  session object not found by container, session id not be received from request

Comment: What error are you facing?

Comment: am not facing any.. error.. but the session handling, is not working...with url rewriting..